# MySQL Limit selection by selecting rownum as start value

Tags: mysql

I got a table with an ID column which is defined as incremental. The rows of this table are filtered by a more complex mysql statement as shown here (SELECT * FROM) therefore I can't use the ID as rownum. What I want is to limit the selection, after it is filtered, starting with a given ID (such as 5) which could be row 1 and ending after the following 10 rows in this case.

This part of the statement is working..

```
SELECT temp.rank 
FROM (
  SELECT @rownum := @rownum+1 rank, f.* FROM function f, (SELECT @rownum :=0) r
) temp
WHERE IDFunc = 5
```

but the complex one including LIMIT not..

```
SELECT *
FROM function 
LIMIT (
  SELECT temp.rank 
  FROM (
    SELECT @rownum := @rownum+1 rank, f.* FROM function f, (SELECT @rownum :=0)r
  ) temp
  WHERE IDFunc = 5
), 10
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

The same reason why

```
mysql> select * from t limit (select 1);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(select 1)' at line 1
```

fails: mysql does not seem to support expressions in the limit.

But you can use local variables and that might give you what you need. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html syntax, and especially section on the LIMIT syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I might have guessed.

So how do local vars work in mysql? Should something like this do it?

```
SELECT @row := 
SELECT temp.rank
FROM (
  SELECT @rownum := @rownum+1 rank, f.* FROM function f, (SELECT @rownum :=0)r
) temp WHERE IDFunc = 1); 
SELECT * 
FROM function 
LIMIT @row, 10
```

I guess I can not put it in one statement?!