# MySQL - generate a list of most 'popular' records

Tags: mysql

I am using the following code to generate a list of how many times a certain release_id appears in a table

So release_id can appear multiple times in my table.

```
SELECT release_id, COUNT( release_id ) 
FROM charts_extended
GROUP BY release_id
ORDER BY COUNT( release_id ) DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Example output

```
release_id COUNT(release_id)
1231287 76
177617 73
12218 67
```

e.g. 1231287 appears 76 times in the table

How can I now output what number in rank the release_id appears

e.g.

1231287 = #1
12218 = #3

'release_id 1231287 is the most popular
'12218 is the 2nd most popular'

Answer (score 3):

Use a rownum simulation.  See this link, it looks like a good article.
http://craftycodeblog.com/2010/09/13/rownum-simulation-with-mysql/

or this one.

[MySQL Limit selection by selecting rownum as start value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584439/mysql-limit-selection-by-selecting-rownum-as-start-value)

Comment: I tested this on a table of my own, and it looks like doing GROUP BY causes problems, perhaps because the rows being returned aren't the rows that were actually taken from the table. The numbers in my row number column end up being out of order.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
select release_id, cnt, @row := @row + 1 rank from (
  select release_id, count(release_id) cnt
  from releases
  group by release_id
  order by cnt desc
  limit 30
) final, (select @row := 0) init
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb4b6/1).

You'll have to use the derived table. If you don't, the order will be scrambled.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like @Steve has a good answer for accomplishing this in MySQL. My 2 cents... I guess it depends on the application, but I usually handle this sort of processing in the business logic. As you parse out the rows, you can just add the row number to them. Some of that will be a performance concern, but -- for me -- it usually just down to keeping the code clean and maintainable.

Based on your `LIMIT 0,30`, I'm guessing you only want to display 30 at a time? If you're wanting to show more than the top 30, I think you'll find it's definitely easier to maintain this in your business logic somewhere. [Here's](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/paging-using-php.aspx) one example of doing "paging" in PHP.