# Optimise & improve performance of this MYSQL query

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT u.id, u.honour, COUNT(*) + 1 AS rank
FROM user_info u
INNER JOIN user_info u2
  ON u.honour < u2.honour
WHERE u.id = '$id'
  AND u2.status = 'Alive'
  AND u2.rank != '14'
```

This query is currently utterly slowing down my server. It works out based on your honour what rank you are within the 'user_info' table which stores it out of all our users.

Screenshot for explain.

http://cl.ly/370z0v2Y3v2X1t1r1k2A

```
SELECT u.id, u.honour, COUNT(*)+1 as rank
FROM user_info u 
    USE INDEX (prestigeOptimiser)
INNER JOIN user_info u2 
    ON u.honour < u2.honour
WHERE u.id='3'
    AND u2.status='Alive'
    AND u2.rank!='14'
```

Comment: You probably need to add some indexes

Comment: Did you notice you don't have any group by?

Comment: can you include an extended explain from your select

Comment: Indexs are set on honour, rank, id and status

Comment: @David are those 4 separate indexes? You need one index covering all 4 fields, I think. Please show us the EXPLAIN on this query.

Comment: See my changes in the post now.

Comment: Thanks for all your help folks i've managed to substantially speed things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the load comes from your join condition '<'.

You could try to split your query or (or if you prefer a subquery) and use the honour index for the count.

```
SELECT id, honour INTO @uid, @uhonour
FROM user_info 
WHERE id = '$id';

SELECT @uid, @uhonour, COUNT(honour) + 1 as rank
FROM user_info
WHERE status = 'Alive'
AND rank != '14'
AND @uhonour < honour;
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should add a `group by` clause so that your query makes sense.

Secondly, you should change the status column to hold an integer to make the index smaller.

Thirdly, you should create an index on id and status like this:

```
alter table user_info add index idxID_Status (id, status)
```

Finally, to obtain ranks you should take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135144/mysql-generate-a-list-of-most-popular-records/10135203#10135203). Additionally you should add a way to order them... getting a rank without order is not really a rank.

Comment: Why do you think the query doesn't make sense? Notice, there's `WHERE u.id = '$id'`, so it's only one user, hence one group.

Comment: @Shedal Did you notice there is no group by and there IS an aggregate function?

Comment: Yes, I did. Just try it out on some simple query. Counting all selected rows does exactly what David tries to achieve in this case.

Comment: @Shedal MySQL allows this. Sytactically, as you said `try it out` it will work. Semantically, it'll depend on what he is expecting to get, but most of the times it is not a good idea not to write a group by.

Comment: It sounds like a bad idea to apply grouping when you don't need to. That's where performance will go down.

Comment: @Shedal MySQL is grouping it anyway... If it doesn't group it, then you're not getting the expected result :)

Answer (score 1):

As we can see from explain, MySQL uses the wrong index here. To start with, just drop all indexes and create a new one, containing at least these two fields: `Id` and `Honour`. It should boost up performance considerably.

```
ALTER TABLE user_info ADD INDEX myIndex (id, honour);
```

Comment: How would this effect the rest of the site which is reliant on the other indexs? Can I have a grouped index and a single index?

Comment: Oh, ok, my advice was a little hurried, I just meant it as an experiment. Then just create this new index, don't drop anything. But then you may need to hint MySQL to use the right index.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Refer to this documentation page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-hints.html

Comment: Did it help when you added the new index and an index hint? I think you may need to apply it to the second (right) table instead of the left one.